# Is POSTing a Dictionary to an .NET MVC action possible?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which contains a series of fields like:

```
<input type="text" name="User[123]" value="Alice" />
<input type="text" name="User[456]" value="Bob" />
...
```

Where the index of the User array (123 and 456) are ID's associated with the value. I'm trying to update these values in the controller.
My thinking is that a Dictionary that maps ID to name would work, but creating the action like:

```
public void Save(Dictionary<string, string> user) {
    // ...
}
```

results in the user parameter being null.

So, is passing a Dictionary possible? or, is there another method to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible for lists, I'm sure it carries over for dictionaries as well.  Read through [Model Binding to a List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) by Phil Haack for some understanding on how list binding works.

You should be able to do this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="User.Index" value="123" />
<input type="text" name="User[123]" value="Alice" />

<input type="hidden" name="User.Index" value="456" />
<input type="text" name="User[456]" value="Bob" />
```

Comment: That post is obsolete. Format for binding to lists changed, you don't need to specify indexes.

Comment: The post is not obsolete.  It was updated with information relevant to MVC 2 and to take into account that ".index" is optional.

Comment: @Levi Are you sure? The code sample above doesn't work for me. I get null as user parameter in Save method. I have MVC 2 RTM and VS 2008.

Comment: Remember - when you model bind to a dictionary, you're actually binding to an ICollection<KeyValuePair<,>>.  So you need User[x].Key and User[x].Value (to reconstitute the KeyValuePair object).  See http://marcomagdy.com/2009/09/03/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-form-inputs-to-action-parameters/ for an example.

Answer (score 8):

See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx for the syntax necessary to bind to a dictionary.  Note in particular the example of binding MSFT + AAPL company tickers around halfway down that post.

Answer (score 8):

For ASP.NET MVC 2 use this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="User[0].Key" value="123" />
<input type="text" name="User[0].Value" value="Alice" />

<input type="hidden" name="User[1].Key" value="456" />
<input type="text" name="User[1].Value" value="Bob" />
```

You need an extra hidden field User[i].Key. i is zero-based index. It should be uninterrupted.

> when you model bind to a dictionary, you're actually binding to an `ICollection<KeyValuePair<,>>`. So you need User[x].Key and User[x].Value (to reconstitute the KeyValuePair object)

**References**

- [ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) by Scott Hanselman
- [ASP.NET MVC Model Binding Form Inputs To Action Parameters](http://marcomagdy.com/2009/09/03/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-form-inputs-to-action-parameters/) by Marco Magdy

Comment: I have created HTML helper extension methods to be able to do this for you: see https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/aspnetmvcdictionaryserialization